# How to open "Linux Programmer's Manual" on installed "POSIX Programmer's Manual"?

Tags: linux, man, posix

How can I open "Linux Programmer's Manual" after having installed "POSIX Programmer's Manual"?

On Ubuntu 18.04 I usually see "Linux Programmer's Manual" by `man` command.
But I wanted to see "POSIX Programmer's Manual", so I installed the package "manpages-posix-dev" by below command.

```
apt install manpages-posix-dev
```

Now I could see "POSIX Programmer's Manual", but I couldn't see "Linux Programmer's Manual" anymore. I want to see "Linux Programmer's Manual" as well.

Answer (score 4):

Consider, for example, you're interested in `printf`.  You can search the manual using the `apropos` command.  My version of that tool accepts a regular expression, so I'll use it to filter out other pages that include `printf` in the name.  If yours doesn't support regular expressions, you can just use `apropos printf` and ignore entries that don't explicitly match what you're looking for:

```
$ apropos '^printf$'
printf (1)           - format and print data
printf (1p)          - write formatted output
printf (3)           - formatted output conversion
printf (3p)          - print formatted output
```

Notice in this case I get 4 results in the manual for things called `printf`. Each version has a number (or a number followed by a character) in parentheses.  That number represents the "section" of the manual in which the corresponding is found.

Now consider that we're interested in the C library function `printf`.  Section 3 of the manual is for library calls, so we'd be interested in one of the last two (or perhaps both).  The one in section 3 is from the Linux Programmer's Manual; the one in section 3p is from the POSIX Programmer's Manual.

When you invoke the `man` command, you can optionally specify the section of the manual to read.  If I want the man page for `printf` from the Linux Programmer's Manaual, I can do:

```
$ man 3 printf
PRINTF(3)              Linux Programmer's Manual             PRINTF(3)
...
```

Alternatively, if I want the man page for `printf` from the POSIX Programmer's Manual, I can do:

```
$ man 3p printf
PRINTF(3P)             POSIX Programmer's Manual            PRINTF(3P)
...
```

See `man man` for more information about the sections of the manual, and what type of information is found in each section:

> The table below shows the section numbers of the manual followed by the types of pages they contain.
>
> 1  Executable programs or shell commands
>   2  System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
>   3  Library calls (functions within program libraries)
>   4  Special files (usually found in /dev)
>   5  File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
>   6  Games
>   7  Miscellaneous  (including  macro  packages  and  conventions), e.g.
>       `man(7)`, `groff(7)`
>   8  System administration commands (usually only for root)
>   9  Kernel routines [Non standard]

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
$ man -a [command name]
```